# issue in layout related to multiple screen support

Tags: android, android-layout, multiscreen

am developing an application which support from 2.3.3 to 4.2. here am developing an application which can support both phone and tablet. for that i created sperate layouts and saved in different folder.
i tested my application with a test device **X-treme 7" Internet tablet** which is android 4.0.1 version. but when i test with my tablet its not take layouts from layout-large folder. but when i test with **emulator which runs android 3.0 OS** it takes layouts from large folder. 
and my doubt is that why my application is not working properly (ie, took layout properly) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X-treme 7" Internet tablet has a resolution of 800x480. With a 7" screen, that puts the pixels per inch somewhere around 80, which falls into very low end of the ldpi scale (which is <=120ppi. To convert a resolution of 800x480 to a [density independent pixel (dp)](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms) screen size, we must multiply by ldpi's scaling of 0.75, which gives us a resolution of 600dp x 360 dp.

As per the [range of screen supported guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range), a `large` screen must be at least 640dp x 480dp, therefore your X-treme 7" Internet tablet should be classified as a `normal` screen device, hence why it is not picking up your `layout-large` layouts.

You can use any number of the [many](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo) [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.screensize) on Google Play to confirm your tablet's screen density and what resources it should be loading.

Comment: I believe you must _divide_ by the abstract bucket, not multiply. The Xtreme 7 tablet should have ~ 1068x640 abstract pixels. Isn't it? :)